# How to make dynamic star rating with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a star rating system for when you visit any restaurant, all the `Attributes' I have to show on UI are dynamic for which I am getting data in JSON format

Here I have five attributes each of them having up to 5 star rating option

My data:

```
    [
          {
            "ATTRIBUTEID": "FOODQUALITY",
            "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Quality Of Food",
            "POSITION": 1
          },
          {
            "ATTRIBUTEID": "CLEANLINESS",
            "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Cleanliness",
            "POSITION": 2
          },
          {
            "ATTRIBUTEID": "SERVICE",
            "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Service",
            "POSITION": 3
          },
          {
            "ATTRIBUTEID": "STAFFBEHAVE",
            "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Staf Behavior",
            "POSITION": 4
          },
          {
            "ATTRIBUTEID": "AMBIENCE",
            "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Ambience",
            "POSITION": 5
          }
        ];
```

What I am trying to achieve is this:

[image]

**What I have done**

```css
@charset "ISO-8859-1";
div.stars {
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -35px;
}

.commonLable {
  margin-left: 55px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

input.star {
  display: none;
}

label.star {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: grey;
  transition: all .2s;
  margin-top: -25px;
}

hr {
  margin: 0;
}

input.star:checked~label.star:before {
  content: '\2605';
  color: #ffd309;
  transition: all .25s;
}

input.star-5:checked~label.star:before {
  color: #ffe840;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
}

input.star-1:checked~label.star:before {
  color: #f24800;
}

label.star:hover {
  transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}

label.star:before {
  content: '\2605';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="stars">
  <form action="">

    <div class="form-row">
      <label class="commonLable"> Cleanliness</label>
      <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
        <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star" value="5" />
        <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
        <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star" value="4" />
        <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
        <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star" value="3" />
        <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
        <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star" value="2" />
        <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
        <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star" value="1" />
        <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <label class="commonLable"> Quality Of Food
</label>
      <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
        <input class="star star-5" id="star-5r" type="radio" name="starr" />
        <label class="star star-5" for="star-5r"></label>
        <input class="star star-4" id="star-4r" type="radio" name="starr" />
        <label class="star star-4" for="star-4r"></label>
        <input class="star star-3" id="star-3r" type="radio" name="starr" />
        <label class="star star-3" for="star-3r"></label>
        <input class="star star-2" id="star-2r" type="radio" name="starr" />
        <label class="star star-2" for="star-2r"></label>
        <input class="star star-1" id="star-1r" type="radio" name="starr" />
        <label class="star star-1" for="star-1r"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

at the end of the form there will be a submit button which will send action to server to save the feedback, as I am lacking in approach I think, like how it will work and how should I do it.

### Edit

I have edited my snippet where I have two attributes `Quality of food`, `Cleanliness` but when I click on `Cleanliness` stars the above star gets colored filled, I know that is because of common css, but that is my issue All the attributes are dynamic, please check my JSON data I have uploaded Image of what I am trying to do.

### Edit

This is dynamic code which is creating stars and labels dynamically

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [{
      "ATTRIBUTEID": "FOODQUALITY",
      "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Quality Of Food",
      "POSITION": 1
    },
    {
      "ATTRIBUTEID": "CLEANLINESS",
      "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Cleanliness",
      "POSITION": 2
    },
    {
      "ATTRIBUTEID": "SERVICE",
      "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Service",
      "POSITION": 3
    },
    {
      "ATTRIBUTEID": "STAFFBEHAVE",
      "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Staf Behavior",
      "POSITION": 4
    },
    {
      "ATTRIBUTEID": "AMBIENCE",
      "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Ambience",
      "POSITION": 5
    }
  ];

  for (v = 0; v < data.length; v++) {

    var container = document.getElementById("container");

    var firstDiv = document.createElement('div');
    firstDiv.setAttribute("class", "form-row");

    var secondDiv = document.createElement('div');
    secondDiv.setAttribute("class", "commonLable");
    secondDiv.append(data[v].ATTRIBUTENAME);


    var thirdDiv = document.createElement('div');
    thirdDiv.setAttribute("class", "form-group col-lg-12");

    /// append stars 

    for (i = 1; i < data.length + 1; i++) {
      var incrementedVar = i + 1;
      var stars = document.createElement("input");
      var label = document.createElement("label");
      stars.setAttribute("type", "radio");
      stars.setAttribute("id", '"' + data[v].ATTRIBUTEID + i + '"');
      stars.setAttribute("name", '"' + data[v].ATTRIBUTEID + i + '"');
      stars.setAttribute("class", "star star-5");
      stars.setAttribute("value", i);
      label.setAttribute("class", "star star-5");
      label.setAttribute("for", '"' + data[v].ATTRIBUTEID + i + '"');
      thirdDiv.append(stars, label);

    }

    secondDiv.append(thirdDiv);
    firstDiv.append(secondDiv);
    container.appendChild(firstDiv);
  }
  $('input:radio').change(
    function() {

      alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```css
@charset "ISO-8859-1";
div.stars {
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -35px;
}

.commonLable {
  margin-left: 55px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

input.star {
  display: none;
}

label.star {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: grey;
  transition: all .2s;
  margin-top: -25px;
}

hr {
  margin: 0;
}

input.star:checked~label.star:before {
  content: '\2605';
  color: #ffd309;
  transition: all .25s;
}

input.star-5:checked~label.star:before {
  color: #ffe840;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
}

input.star-1:checked~label.star:before {
  color: #f24800;
}

label.star:hover {
  transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}

label.star:before {
  content: '\2605';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<div class="stars">
  <form action="" id="container">

  </form>
</div>
```

In the second snippet I have added the dynamic code which is not taking css correctly.

Issue: once if I had marked the stars and want to unmarked them from 4 to 2 it is not happening. Please check snippet 1 where I have static code using HTML, I want that type of functionality.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Your code seems to be working fine. All you're missing is the `value` attributes on the radio buttons for them to send any values to the server when the form is submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example not work because the inputs in each `form-group` not have the same `name`. Give them the same `name` will solve your problem.

Your stars is `float: right` so you need to append the stars in descending order to make them work as expected, else the first star on the left will have value `5`.

And I also simplify your code to use element property instead of `setAttribute()` method:

```js
var data = [
  {
    "ATTRIBUTEID": "FOODQUALITY",
    "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Quality Of Food",
    "POSITION": 1
  },
  {
    "ATTRIBUTEID": "CLEANLINESS",
    "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Cleanliness",
    "POSITION": 2
  },
  {
    "ATTRIBUTEID": "SERVICE",
    "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Service",
    "POSITION": 3
  },
  {
    "ATTRIBUTEID": "STAFFBEHAVE",
    "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Staf Behavior",
    "POSITION": 4
  },
  {
    "ATTRIBUTEID": "AMBIENCE",
    "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Ambience",
    "POSITION": 5
  }
];

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  var container = document.getElementById("container");

  var row = document.createElement('div');
  row.className = "form-row";

  var commonLabel = document.createElement('label');
  commonLabel.className = "commonLable";
  commonLabel.innerHTML = data[i].ATTRIBUTENAME;


  var form_group = document.createElement('div');
  form_group.className = "form-group col-lg-12";

  for (j = 5;j > 0; j--) {
    var star = document.createElement("input");
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    star.type = "radio";
    star.id = data[i].ATTRIBUTEID + j;
    star.name = data[i].ATTRIBUTEID;
    star.className = "star star-" + j;
    star.value = j;
    label.className = "star star-" + j;
    label.htmlFor = data[i].ATTRIBUTEID + j;
    form_group.append(star, label);
  }

  row.append(commonLabel, form_group);
  container.appendChild(row);
}

$('#submit').click(function(){
  var formData = $('#container').serialize();
  alert(formData);
});
```

```css
div.stars {
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.commonLable {
  margin-left: 55px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input.star {
  display: none;
} 

label.star {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: grey;
  transition: all .2s;
}

input.star:checked~label.star:before {
  content: '\2605';
  color: #FD4;
  transition: all .25s;
}

input.star-5:checked~label.star:before {
  color: #FE7;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
}

input.star-1:checked~label.star:before {
  color: #F62;
}

label.star:hover {
  transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}

label.star:before {
  content: '\2605';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="stars">
  <form action="" id="container">
   
  </form>
  <button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @manishthakur I have editted my answer to solve the problem you mentioned. Please check.

Comment: Yes. What is your doubt?

Comment: sir as per my question you have helped me with correct approach but I need some suggestion regarding saving data in DB in my backend

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198302/discussion-between-cuong-le-ngoc-and-manish-thakur).

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can create a dynamic star rating.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "ATTRIBUTEID": "FOODQUALITY",
    "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Quality Of Food",
    "POSITION": 1
  },
  {
    "ATTRIBUTEID": "CLEANLINESS",
    "Quantity": "Cleanliness",
    "POSITION": 2
  },
  {
    "ATTRIBUTEID": "SERVICE",
    "Quantity": "Service",
    "POSITION": 3
  },
  {
    "ATTRIBUTEID": "STAFFBEHAVE",
    "Quantity": "Staf Behavior",
    "POSITION": 4
  },
  {
    "ATTRIBUTEID": "AMBIENCE",
    "Quantity": "Ambience",
    "POSITION": 5
  }
];

for (v=0;v<data.length - 1;v++){
  var container = document.getElementById("container");

  var firstDiv = document.createElement('div');
  firstDiv.setAttribute("class", "form-row");

  var secondDiv = document.createElement('div');
  secondDiv.setAttribute("class", "commonLable");
  secondDiv.append(data[v].ATTRIBUTEID);


  var thirdDiv = document.createElement('div');
  thirdDiv.setAttribute("class", "form-group col-lg-12");

  /// append stars 

  for (i=0;i<5;i++){
   var incrementedVar = i+1;
    var stars = document.createElement("input");
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    stars.setAttribute("type", "radio");
    stars.setAttribute("id", '"'+ data[v].ATTRIBUTEID + i +'"');
    stars.setAttribute("name", '"'+ data[v].ATTRIBUTEID + i +'"');
    stars.setAttribute("class", "star star-5");
    label.setAttribute("class", "star star-5");
    label.setAttribute("for", '"'+ data[v].ATTRIBUTEID + i +'"');
    thirdDiv.append(stars, label);

  }

  secondDiv.append(thirdDiv);
  firstDiv.append(secondDiv);
  container.appendChild(firstDiv);
}
```

```css
div.stars {
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.commonLable {
  margin-left: 55px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input.star {
  display: none;
} 

label.star {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: grey;
  transition: all .2s;
}

input.star:checked~label.star:before {
  content: '\2605';
  color: #FD4;
  transition: all .25s;
}

input.star-5:checked~label.star:before {
  color: #FE7;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
}

input.star-1:checked~label.star:before {
  color: #F62;
}

label.star:hover {
  transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}

label.star:before {
  content: '\2605';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="stars">
  <form action="" id="container">
   
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: hey that's cool, but I want to make it dynamic as you can check my JSON data there Attribute name And Ids are there I cant predict how many attributes will be there,here just for example I have done it statically for two attributes i.e `Quality Of Food` and `Cleanliness`, i want to do it with javascript or jquery dynamically

Comment: and one more thing you haven't notice, when I give  some satrs to first one and the clicks on second one i.e `Cleanliness` the first attribute star disappears

Comment: I have got your point soon share code with you. Second point is handled with  the ids and name changing.

Comment: @manishthakuri have updated the answer, now its totally dynamic. I hope you can handle rest now.

Comment: hey but only radio buttons are showing up no stars, it is not taking css

Comment: @manishthakuryeah i have mentioned that above there is an issue in css

Comment: I didn't get you where?

Comment: I have found the bug with css its fixed i'm updating the answer in few minutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198137/discussion-between-abdulhaq-shah-and-manish-thakur).

Answer (score 1):

Check code snipet below I have made some corrections, added submit button to get result

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [{
      "ATTRIBUTEID": "FOODQUALITY",
      "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Quality Of Food",
      "POSITION": 1
    },
    {
      "ATTRIBUTEID": "CLEANLINESS",
      "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Cleanliness",
      "POSITION": 2
    },
    {
      "ATTRIBUTEID": "SERVICE",
      "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Service",
      "POSITION": 3
    },
    {
      "ATTRIBUTEID": "STAFFBEHAVE",
      "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Staf Behavior",
      "POSITION": 4
    },
    {
      "ATTRIBUTEID": "AMBIENCE",
      "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Ambience",
      "POSITION": 5
    }
  ];

  for (v = 0; v < data.length; v++) {

    var container = document.getElementById("container");

    var firstDiv = document.createElement('div');
    firstDiv.setAttribute("class", "form-row");

    var secondDiv = document.createElement('div');
    secondDiv.setAttribute("class", "commonLable");
    secondDiv.append(data[v].ATTRIBUTENAME);


    var thirdDiv = document.createElement('div');
    thirdDiv.setAttribute("class", "form-group col-lg-12");

    /// append stars 

    for (i = 1; i < data.length + 1; i++) {
      var incrementedVar = i + 1;
      var stars = document.createElement("input");
      var label = document.createElement("label");
      stars.setAttribute("type", "radio");
      stars.setAttribute("required", "required");
      stars.setAttribute("id", data[v].ATTRIBUTEID + i ); // removed double quotes
      stars.setAttribute("name",  data[v].ATTRIBUTEID );  // removed incremental i, removed double quotes
      stars.setAttribute("class", "star star-5");
      stars.setAttribute("value", i);
      label.setAttribute("class", "star star-5");
      label.setAttribute("for",  data[v].ATTRIBUTEID + i);  // removed double quotes
      thirdDiv.append(stars, label);

    }

    secondDiv.append(thirdDiv);
    firstDiv.append(secondDiv);
    container.appendChild(firstDiv);
    
  }
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.type = 'submit'; 
    btn.value= 'submit';
    btn.innerHTML = 'Submit'; 
    btn.setAttribute("style", "margin-left:55px;");
    container.append(btn);
  $('input:radio').change(
    function() {
    });
  $('.buttonSubmit').click(function(){
    var formData = $('#container').serialize();
    alert(formData);
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "ISO-8859-1";
div.stars {
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -35px;
}

.commonLable {
  margin-left: 55px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

input.star {
  display: none;
}

label.star {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: grey;
  transition: all .2s;
  margin-top: -25px;
}

hr {
  margin: 0;
}

input.star:checked~label.star:before {
  content: '\2605';
  color: #ffd309;
  transition: all .25s;
}

input.star-5:checked~label.star:before {
  color: #ffe840;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
}

input.star-1:checked~label.star:before {
  color: #f24800;
}

label.star:hover {
  transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}

label.star:before {
  content: '\2605';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<div class="stars">
  <form action="" id="container">

  </form>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> If i had marked the stars and want to unmarked them from 4 to 2 it is not happening...

You yellowish the stars using the following CSS rule:

```
input.star:checked~label.star:before {
```

That applies on all `label.star` **following** a checked checkbox.

Now to un-yellowish... You simply have to uncheck the **sibling inputs**... I used [`.siblings(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to match them... And an `.each()` loop to change the `checked` property to false.

```
$(this).siblings("input").each(function() {
  $(this).prop("checked", false);
});
```

**Here is a snippet**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [{
      "ATTRIBUTEID": "FOODQUALITY",
      "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Quality Of Food",
      "POSITION": 1
    },
    {
      "ATTRIBUTEID": "CLEANLINESS",
      "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Cleanliness",
      "POSITION": 2
    },
    {
      "ATTRIBUTEID": "SERVICE",
      "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Service",
      "POSITION": 3
    },
    {
      "ATTRIBUTEID": "STAFFBEHAVE",
      "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Staf Behavior",
      "POSITION": 4
    },
    {
      "ATTRIBUTEID": "AMBIENCE",
      "ATTRIBUTENAME": "Ambience",
      "POSITION": 5
    }
  ];

  for (v = 0; v < data.length; v++) {

    var container = document.getElementById("container");

    var firstDiv = document.createElement('div');
    firstDiv.setAttribute("class", "form-row");

    var secondDiv = document.createElement('div');
    secondDiv.setAttribute("class", "commonLable");
    secondDiv.append(data[v].ATTRIBUTENAME);


    var thirdDiv = document.createElement('div');
    thirdDiv.setAttribute("class", "form-group col-lg-12");

    /// append stars 

    for (i = 1; i < data.length + 1; i++) {
      var incrementedVar = i + 1;
      var stars = document.createElement("input");
      var label = document.createElement("label");
      stars.setAttribute("type", "radio");
      stars.setAttribute("id", data[v].ATTRIBUTEID + i);
      stars.setAttribute("name", data[v].ATTRIBUTEID + i);
      stars.setAttribute("class", "star star-5");
      stars.setAttribute("value", i);
      label.setAttribute("class", "star star-5");
      label.setAttribute("for", data[v].ATTRIBUTEID + i);
      thirdDiv.append(stars, label);

    }

    secondDiv.append(thirdDiv);
    firstDiv.append(secondDiv);
    container.appendChild(firstDiv);
  }


  $('input:radio').on("change", function() {
console.log($(this).prop("checked"));
    // Uncheck all sibling inputs that are before $(this) (in DOM... But visually on the right).
    $(this).siblings("input").each(function() {
      $(this).prop("checked", false);
    });
  });

});
```

```css
@charset "ISO-8859-1";
div.stars {
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -35px;
}

.commonLable {
  margin-left: 55px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

input.star {
  display: none;
}

label.star {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: grey;
  transition: all .2s;
  margin-top: -25px;
}

hr {
  margin: 0;
}

input.star:checked~label.star:before {
  content: '\2605';
  color: #ffd309;
  transition: all .25s;
}

input.star-5:checked~label.star:before {
  color: #ffe840;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
}

input.star-1:checked~label.star:before {
  color: #f24800;
}

label.star:hover {
  transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}

label.star:before {
  content: '\2605';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<div class="stars">
  <form action="" id="container">

  </form>
</div>
```